# Start network capture as soon as interface is up

Tags: usb, ethernet, wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to debug the network traffic that happens right when a USB RNDIS network adapter is plugged in. Right now I can use Wireshark to analyze the traffic after the USB has already been plugged in, but I can't start the capture except for manually after the interface is up (and the packets I'm most interested in have already past by)

Is there any way to automatically start capture when an interface appears? Or just pause capture while it's gone?

If this is not possible in Wireshark, is there another program that could capture this traffic?

Answer (score 1):

A solution exists for Windows, using
[USBPcap](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/),
an open-source USB sniffer for Windows that is integrated with Wireshark.
This uses the program `USBPcapCMD.exe` that is also installed by Wireshark.

The method is discussed in detail in the article
[USB Packet capture for Windows Tour](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/tour.html),
but here is a summary:

- Plug in the device and use `USBPcapCMD.exe` to identify the Root Hub
  that this device is connected to
- Unplug the device and stop `USBPcapCMD.exe`
- Run `USBPcapCMD.exe` again, select the Root Hub and define the output
  `.pcap` file
- Plug-in the device
- Press Ctrl+C to stop collecting data
- Start Wireshark and open the `.pcap` file to analyze it.

You may also do live capture in Wireshark by entering in a
Command Prompt (cmd) run as Administrator a command similar to
the following :

```
USBPcapCMD.exe -d \\.\USBPcap2 -o - | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -
```

Comment: This worked to capture the data... now I'm just struggling to analyze the packets.